# Getting Rid of Duplicates And Combining Info

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Currently writing a SQL Server query that displays a whole bunch of info and currently, it's spitting out the right info but big chunks of it are duplicates and some areas should be combined.  Note, that the `StateAcronym` part is actually something new - it all worked hunky dory prior to adding the `StateAcronym` but then it went all duplicate/non-combining - like.

My code:

```
DECLARE @BulkInfo TABLE (
       ZoneID INT,
   ZoneName VARCHAR(100),
   StateAcronym VARCHAR(5),
   SiteID BIGINT,
   SiteGroupID INT,
   Papers BIGINT
    );

INSERT INTO @BulkInfo (ZoneID, ZoneName, StateAcronym, SiteID, SiteGroupID, Papers)
   SELECT DISTINCT
    z.ZoneID,
    ISNULL(z.ZoneName,'NO ZONE'),
    (case when z.ZoneName is not null and z.ZoneName <> 'No Zone'
          then st.StateAcronym
    else null
        end) as StateAcronym,
    s.SiteID,
    wfset.SiteEventID,
    COUNT(distinct c.PaperID) Papers
   FROM 
      Sites s 
   LEFT JOIN 
      SiteLoc sl ON s.SiteID = sl.SiteID
   LEFT JOIN 
      States st ON sl.StateID = st.StateID
   LEFT JOIN 
      Zones z ON sl.ZoneID = z.ZoneID
   LEFT JOIN 
      WFSite wfse ON s.SiteID = wfse.SiteID AND StatusID IN (1,2)
   LEFT JOIN 
      WFSiteTypes wfset ON wfse.TypeID = wfset.TypeID
   LEFT JOIN 
      Papers c ON s.SiteID = c.SiteID
   WHERE
    s.ProjectID = 110
   GROUP BY 
    z.ZoneID,
    z.ZoneName,
    st.StateAcronym,
    s.SiteID,
    wfset.SiteGroupID,
    wfse.TypeID

SELECT DISTINCT
    t.ZoneName,
    t.StateAcronym,
    TotalSites,
    TotalPapers,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),TotPer) 'TotPer%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesType1, 0) TotalSitesType1,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersType1, 0) TotalPapersType1,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type1Per),0) 'Type1Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesType2,0) TotalSitesType2,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersType2,0) TotalPapersType2,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type2Per),0) 'Type2Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesType3, 0) TotalSitesType3,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersType3, 0) TotalPapersType3,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type3Per),0) 'Type3Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesType4,0) TotalSitesType4,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersType4,0) TotalPapersType4,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type4Per),0) 'Type4Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesType5,0) TotalSitesType5,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersType5,0) TotalPapersType5,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type5Per),0) 'Type5Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesType6,0) TotalSitesType6,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersType6,0) TotalPapersType6,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type6Per),0) 'Type6Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesType7,0) TotalSitesType7,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersType7,0) TotalPapersType7,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type7Per),0) 'Type7Per%'
FROM 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateAcronym,
    COUNT(distinct SiteID) TotalSites,
    SUM(distinct Papers) TotalPapers,
    SUM(distinct Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(distinct Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) TotPer
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateAcronym) t
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateAcronym,
    COUNT(distinct SiteID) TotalSitesType1,
    SUM(distinct Papers) TotalPapersType1,
    SUM(distinct Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(distinct Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Type1Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteGroupID = 2
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateAcronym) f ON t.ZoneName = f.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateAcronym,
    COUNT(distinct SiteID) TotalSitesType2,
    SUM(distinct Papers) TotalPapersType2,
    SUM(distinct Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(distinct Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Type2Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteGroupID = 3
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateAcronym) o ON t.ZoneName = o.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateAcronym,
    COUNT(distinct SiteID) TotalSitesType3,
    SUM(distinct Papers) TotalPapersType3,
    SUM(distinct Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(distinct Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Type3Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteGroupID = 4
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateAcronym) fm ON t.ZoneName = fm.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateAcronym,
    COUNT(distinct SiteID) TotalSitesType4,
    SUM(distinct Papers) TotalPapersType4,
    SUM(distinct Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(distinct Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Type4Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteGroupID = 6
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateAcronym) r ON t.ZoneName = r.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateAcronym,
    COUNT(distinct SiteID) TotalSitesType5,
    SUM(distinct Papers) TotalPapersType5,
    SUM(distinct Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(distinct Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Type5Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteGroupID = 7
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateAcronym) cs ON t.ZoneName = cs.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateAcronym,
    COUNT(distinct SiteID) TotalSitesType6,
    SUM(distinct Papers) TotalPapersType6,
    SUM(distinct Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(distinct Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Type6Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteGroupID = 9
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateAcronym) d ON t.ZoneName = d.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateAcronym,
    COUNT(distinct SiteID) TotalSitesType7,
    SUM(distinct Papers) TotalPapersType7,
    SUM(distinct Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(distinct Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Type7Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteGroupID = 8
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateAcronym) m ON t.ZoneName = m.ZoneName

ORDER BY t.ZoneName, t.StateShortCode
```

Here is a bit of a sample of what the query is spitting out

```
ZoneName | StateAcronym | TotalSites | TotalPapers | TotPer% | TotalSitesType1 | TotalPapersType1 | Type1Per% | TotalSitesType2 | TotalPapersType2 | Type2Per% | TotalSitesType3 | TotalPapersType3 | Type3Per% | TotalSitesType4 | TotalPapersType4 | Type4Per% | TotalSitesType5 | TotalPapersType5 | Type5Per% | TotalSitesType6 | TotalPapersType6 | Type6Per% | TotalSitesType7 | TotalPapersType7 | Type7Per%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| NJ           | 64         | 198         | 0.19    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 8               | 46               | 0.04      | 900             | 2881             | 2.74      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 1               | 6                | 0.01      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| NJ           | 64         | 198         | 0.19    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 8               | 46               | 0.04      | 900             | 2881             | 2.74      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 47              | 475              | 0.45      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| NJ           | 64         | 198         | 0.19    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 8               | 46               | 0.04      | 55              | 174              | 0.17      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 1               | 6                | 0.01      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| NJ           | 64         | 198         | 0.19    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 8               | 46               | 0.04      | 55              | 174              | 0.17      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 47              | 475              | 0.45      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| NJ           | 64         | 198         | 0.19    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 316             | 4167             | 3.96      | 55              | 174              | 0.17      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 1               | 6                | 0.01      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| NJ           | 64         | 198         | 0.19    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 316             | 4167             | 3.96      | 55              | 174              | 0.17      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 47              | 475              | 0.45      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| NJ           | 64         | 198         | 0.19    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 316             | 4167             | 3.96      | 900             | 2881             | 2.74      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 1               | 6                | 0.01      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| NJ           | 64         | 198         | 0.19    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 316             | 4167             | 3.96      | 900             | 2881             | 2.74      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 47              | 475              | 0.45      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| PA           | 2123       | 7764        | 7.38    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 8               | 46               | 0.04      | 55              | 174              | 0.17      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 1               | 6                | 0.01      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| PA           | 2123       | 7764        | 7.38    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 8               | 46               | 0.04      | 55              | 174              | 0.17      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 47              | 475              | 0.45      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| PA           | 2123       | 7764        | 7.38    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 8               | 46               | 0.04      | 900             | 2881             | 2.74      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 1               | 6                | 0.01      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| PA           | 2123       | 7764        | 7.38    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 8               | 46               | 0.04      | 900             | 2881             | 2.74      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 47              | 475              | 0.45      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| PA           | 2123       | 7764        | 7.38    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 316             | 4167             | 3.96      | 55              | 174              | 0.17      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 1               | 6                | 0.01      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| PA           | 2123       | 7764        | 7.38    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 316             | 4167             | 3.96      | 55              | 174              | 0.17      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 47              | 475              | 0.45      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| PA           | 2123       | 7764        | 7.38    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 316             | 4167             | 3.96      | 900             | 2881             | 2.74      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 1               | 6                | 0.01      | 39              | 133              | 0.13    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZoneName1| PA           | 2123       | 7764        | 7.38    | 648             | 2332             | 2.22      | 316             | 4167             | 3.96      | 900             | 2881             | 2.74      | 0               | 0                | 0.00      | 161             | 1017             | 0.97      | 47              | 475              | 0.45      | 39              | 133              | 0.13
```

I understand why it's a little off, since the same zone could be assigned to different StateAcronyms but I'm not sure why it still displays multiple and doesn't combine the info

Comment: I see no duplicates in the sample output provided.

Comment: I think I meant to use a different word - but technically what I would like to see is just two rows with ZoneName1 | NJ .... and ZoneName1 | PA..... I'm not sure why some area are producing different numbers and are not combining the info into one distinct row.

Comment: There are 2 different values for `TotalSitesType2` for `ZoneName1`, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look across your output you will see that there are not actually any duplicates.

I'm guessing you have multiple `StateAcronym` values being returned by your subqueries, and therefore need to change your `JOIN` criteria to:

```
ON t.ZoneName = f.ZoneName
 AND t.StateAcronym = f.StateAcronym
```

A simple test in this situation would be to run one of your subqueries, limiting to a single `ZoneName`, I'm betting that if you run:

```
SELECT 
    ZoneName,
    StateAcronym,
    COUNT(distinct SiteID) TotalSites,
    SUM(distinct Papers) TotalPapers,
    SUM(distinct Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(distinct Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) TotPer
FROM  @BulkInfo
WHERE ZoneName = 'ZoneName1'
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateAcronym
```

You'll get more than 1 row due to different `StateAcronym` values.